# SwiftUI GoogleMap Delegate Events Causes Infinite Body View Reloading

Tags: swiftui

Im new to SwiftUI and Im using google maps within my app, I need to track 2 Map events as shown in below code,

Main View :

```
   struct HomeView : View {
    @State var mapView = GMSMapView()
    @State var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @State var alert = false
    @State var currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    @State var isLocationChanged = false
    var body: some View{
        
        ZStack{
        
            MapView(mapView: self.$mapView, locationManager: self.$locationManager, alert: self.$alert, currentLocation: self.$currentLocation, isLocationChanged: self.$isLocationChanged)
                .equatable()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                .onAppear{
                    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                }
            if isLocationChanged {
                
                Text("Show Search Progress")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding(.vertical,10)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)
            }
        }// Show Alert
    }
}
```

MapView :

```
struct MapView : UIViewRepresentable, Equatable {

@Binding var mapView : GMSMapView
@Binding var locationManager : CLLocationManager
@Binding var alert : Bool
@Binding var currentLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D
@Binding var isLocationChanged : Bool

static func == (lhs: MapView, rhs: MapView) -> Bool {
    return lhs.isLocationChanged == rhs.isLocationChanged && lhs.isLocationChanged != rhs.isLocationChanged
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView {
  
    mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    locationManager.delegate = context.coordinator
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    return mapView
}
    
func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
 
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    mapView.animate(toLocation: self.currentLocation)
    mapView.animate(toZoom: 15)
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(googlemapview: self)
}

class Coordinator : NSObject, GMSMapViewDelegate , CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var parent : MapView
    
    init( googlemapview : MapView) {
        self.parent = googlemapview
    }
    
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.parent.currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        self.parent.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        self.parent.isLocationChanged = false
        print("=========  Idle")

    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
        self.parent.isLocationChanged = true
        print("================ Changed")
    }
}
```

}

As shown every time the map view rendered it will fire the didChange events which will make the whole view body to reload even the map its self and this will cause an infinite main view reloading, how can i fix this ?

**Update**

I tried to use EquatableView to ignore the changes from the Map View  but Im still getting the same results and the mapView will be redrawn evert time i scroll it ??!! I need to track when user scroll the map to new position

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to location manager recreated, try with `StateObject`

```
struct GoogleMapsView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @StateObject private var locationManager = LoccationManager() // << here !!

//...
}
```

Comment: This kind of solve half of the issue, but its now reload the view on the `idleAt position` event

Comment: I don't think it is correct to toggle self.isPositionChanged unconditionally, you have to check by equality if it is really changed, somewhere.